# How to append last row from 2D array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

How can I append the last row of an array to itself ?

something like:

```
x= np.array([(1,2,3,4,5)])
x= np.append(x, x[0], 1)
```

Also, Could you explain why this way of working with vectors yields an error?

```
for i in range(3):
    x.append(0)

x
[0, 0, 0]

x= np.append(x, x[0],0)
```

Which way of working with vectors would be best ? I am trying to work with 2D vectors as being a matrix, keeping in mind i would like to do some future matrix calculations like multiplication etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [3]: x=np.array([(1,2,3,4,5)])
In [4]: x
Out[4]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
In [5]: x=np.append(x,x[0],1)
...
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

`x` is (1,5), `x[0]` is (5,) - one is 2d, the other 1d.

```
In [11]: x=np.vstack([x,x[0]])
In [12]: x
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

this works because `vstack` changes the `x[0]` to 2d, e.g. (1,5), so it can concatenate it with `x`.

```
In [16]: x=np.concatenate([x, np.atleast_2d(x[-1,:])])
In [17]: x.shape
Out[17]: (3, 5)
```

We can use `concatenate` (or append) by first expanding `x[-1,:]` to 2d.

But in general repeated concatenation is a slow way of building an array.

For a list, repeated append like this works.  But it does not work for arrays. For one thing, an array does not have an `append` method.  And `np.append` function returns a new array.  It does not change `x` in place.

```
In [19]: z=[]
In [20]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     z.append(0)
    ...:     
In [21]: z
Out[21]: [0, 0, 0]
```

Repeated append to a list is fine.  Repeated append to an array is slow.

```
In [25]: z=[]
In [26]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     z.append(list(range(i,i+4)))

In [27]: z
Out[27]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
In [28]: np.array(z)
Out[28]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. i would like to ask if you have any experience with np.array in 2d vs matrix ? I am obviously new to python, and i would like to do some matrix calculations in the future so which would you recommend ?

Comment: `np.matrix` is a subclass of `np.ndarray` that is restricted to 2 dimensions.  It makes code a little more familiar for MATLAB users.  You can do all your matrix calculations with numpy arrays (there's no speed  difference).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> np.append(x,x[-1:],0)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
np.append(arr=x, values=x[-1,None], axis=0)
#array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```